# Getting list in JSON at Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

I want to get the "Data" list passed from my javascript to python FLASK APP and than work on the list "Data"
JavaScript code to send is

```
function fetch()
    {
     var jsonObj={'email':"testuser4@test.tld",'Data': ['Name','Phone']};
      $.ajax({
                 url:'http://192.168.56.102:5000/fetch',
                 data:jsonObj,
                 type:"POST",
                 dataType:"json",
                 crossDomain:true
             }).done(function(result){console.log(result)}).fail(function(result){console.log("error")});
    }
```

The Python FLASK code is

```
@app.route("/fetch", methods=["POST"])
def fetch():
    print request.json
    return jsonify({"Status":200})
```

from the print statement above I get

> ImmutableMultiDict([('Data[]', u'Name'), ('Data[]', u'Phone'),
>   ('email', u'testuser4@test.tld')])

But I want to get something like this

> ImmutableMultiDict( { 'email': 'testuser4@test.tld', 'Data' :
>   ['Name','Email'] } )

In short I want to get the list in server side so send by JSON.

PS : I have already tried [How to get a JSON Object in Python (Flask Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31448194/how-to-get-a-json-object-in-python-flask-framework)
but on implementing this I am getting

> ImmutableMultiDict([])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the data to JSON yourself, and use `contentType` to set the content-type header.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'http://192.168.56.102:5000/fetch',
   data: JSON.stringify(jsonObj),
   type:"POST",
   contentType:"application/json",
   ...
```